# Tikz, Tree without overlaps

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm trying to get a nice tree without the overlaps, can anyone help me to improve my code?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,level/.style={level distance=20mm, sibling distance =35mm/#1},scale=1]
        \node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
            child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                    child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                    child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                        child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                            child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                        }
                    }
                }   
                child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                    child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                        child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                            child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                                child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                                child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                        child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                            child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                                child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                                child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the `sibling distance` for some of the levels:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  baseline,
  level distance=20mm,
  text depth=.1em,
  text height=.8em,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=10em},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=40em},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=20em},
  level 4/.style={sibling distance=10em}]
        \node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
            child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                    child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                    child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                        child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                            child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                        }
                    }
                }   
                child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                    child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                        child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                            child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                                child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                                child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                        child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                            child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            child{ node [ellipse split, draw] {$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                                child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                                child{ node [rectangle, draw] {$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Instead of manually adjusting the `sibling distance` you can use [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package which does it for you.

Next it's the abstract from the manual.

> Forest is a pgf/TikZ-based package for drawing linguistic (and other
>   kinds of) trees. Its main features are (i) a packing algorithm which
>   can produce very compact trees; (ii) a user-friendly interface
>   consisting of the familiar bracket encoding of trees plus the
>   key–value interface to option- setting; (iii) many tree-formatting
>   options, with control over option values of individual nodes and
>   mechanisms for their manipulation; (iv) the possibility to decorate
>   the tree using the full power of pgf/TikZ; (v) an externalization
>   mechanism sensitive to code-changes.

And next is your code adapted to forest syntax which is similar to the one used with `qtree`. As you can see no `level` or `sibling distance` is declared, the package computes
them to produce a compact tree. Of course, you can change them with options.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}  
\centering
\begin{forest}
    rounded/.style={ellipse split, draw},
    squared/.style={rectangle,draw}
    [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}, for tree=rounded
        [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
            [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                    [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                    [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                        [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                    ]
                ]
            ]   
            [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                    [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                    [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                        [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                            [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                            [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
                [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                    [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                    [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                        [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                        [{$s_1<s_2$\nodepart{lower}\tiny $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$}
                            [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                            [{$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$},squared]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
       ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]