# Overlapping nodes in a red-black tree in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, overlap

I took the example of a red-black tree from the [TikZ examples page](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/) and adjusted it for my own needs, but I get overlapping nodes in the bottom level of the tree:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        treenode/.style = {align=center, circle, draw=black, inner sep=0pt, text centered, font=\sffamily, thick, text width=2em},
        w/.style = {treenode, black},
        b/.style = {treenode, white, fill=black},
        level/.style = {sibling distance=0.45\textwidth/#1}
    }
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node [w] {15-8}
                        child {node [b] {4-9}
                            child {node [w] {4-2}}
                            child {node [w] {2-1}}
                            child {node [w] {3-1}}
                        }
                        child {node [b] {4-6}
                            child {node [w] {3-1}}
                            child {node [w] {3-3}}
                        };
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{1}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                \caption{2}
            \end{subfigure}
            \vskip\baselineskip
            \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                \caption{3}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                \caption{4}
            \end{subfigure}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

I've tried fiddling with the `sibling distance` parameter but can't get it to space out the nodes properly.

I've looked at some other answers but they use different packages to draw trees. Is there a good way to draw such trees in tikz without overlapping? Possibly using all the available `0.45\textwidth` to space out the leaf nodes?

Comment: Here you have two solutions, the manual one which plays with `sibbling distance` and the automatic which replaces tikz-tree with `forest`. You can choose:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86919/tikz-tree-without-overlaps/87004#87004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `forest` is simple (as mentioned [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi) in his comment):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
   \begin{forest}
   for tree = {circle, draw, minimum size=4ex, inner sep=2pt,
where level = 1{fill=black, text=white}{},
       grow = south
               } 
 [15-8
    [4-9
        [4-2]
        [2-1]
        [3-1]
    ]
    [4-6
        [3-1]
        [3-3]
    ]
 ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]