# overlapping due to many entries in Tikz trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-trees

I want to use **Tikz Trees** to represent a classification, my problem is that I have many entries so they overlap, and if I increase the spacing as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86919/tikz-tree-without-overlaps/86921#86921) the figure will go outside the boundaries,

can you please tell me how I can fix this issue? thanks in advance.

[image]

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
[   
    level 1/.style = {red,    sibling distance = 110mm, level distance = 8mm},
    level 2/.style = {blue,   sibling distance = 35mm,  level distance = 10mm},
    level 3/.style = {teal,   sibling distance = 30mm,  level distance = 12mm},
    level 4/.style = {violet, sibling distance = 06mm,  level distance = 30mm},
    level 5/.style = {gray,   sibling distance = 08mm,  level distance = 30mm},
    every node/.append style = {draw, align=center},
    grow=right,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) |- (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)},
]
\node {\textbf{Human Variability}}
    %
    child { node {Cognitive}
        %%
        child {node {individual}
            %%-%
            child {node {intra-personal}
                child { node {Situation Awareness}}
                child { node {Attention}}
                child { node {Motivation}}
            }
            child {node {inter-personal}
                %%-%%
                child {node {Cognitive Load}
                    %%-%%-%
                    child {node {Comprehension}}
                    child {node {Mental Capacity}}
                }
                child { node {Experience}}
                child { node {Satisfaction}}
                child { node {Trust}}
                child { node {Curiosity}}
                child { node {Frustration}}
                child { node {Acceptability}}
                child { node {Usability}}
                child { node {Task Engagement}}
            }
        }
        child {node {Temporal}
            %%-%
            child {node {Volatile}
                %%-%%
                child { node {Curiosity}}
                child { node {Situation Awareness}}
                child { node {Attention}}
                child { node[anchor=north]{Trust}}
                child { node {Frustration}}
                child { node {Task Engagement}}
                child { node {Motivation}}
            }
            child {node {Consistent}
                %%-%
                child {node {Cognitive Load}
                    %%-%%
                    child {node {Comprehension}}
                    child {node {Mental Capacity}}
                }
                child { node {Experience}}
                child { node [anchor=north]{Satisfaction}}
                child { node {Acceptability}}
                child { node {Usability}}
            }
        }
    }
    child {node {Physical}
        %%
        child {node {individual}
            %%-%
            child {node {intra-personal}
                %%-%%
                child {node [anchor= north]{Motor Variability}
                    %%-%%-%
                    child {node {Motion Trajectory}}
                    child {node [anchor= north]{Posture}}
                    child {node {Torque and Force}}
                }
                child {node [anchor=north]{Muscular Fatigue}}
                child{node{Heart Rate Variability (HRV)}}
            }
            child {node {inter-personal}
                %%-%%
                child {node [anchor= north]{laterality (dominant hand)}}
            }
            }
        child {node {Temporal}
            %%-%
            child {node {Volatile}
                %%-%%
                child { node {Motor Variability}
                    %%-%%-%
                    child {node {Motion Trajectory}}
                    child {node [anchor=north]{Posture}}
                    child {node {Torque and Force}}
                }
                child{node{Heart Rate Variability (HRV)}}
            }
            child {node {Consistent}
                %%-%%
                child {node [anchor=north]{laterality (dominant hand)}}
                child{ node{Anthropometric Variability}
                    %%-%%-%
                    child {node {Body Dimensions}}
                    child {node [anchor=north]{Gender}}
                    child {node {Age}}
                }
            }
        }
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Human Variability Classification}
\label{fig:HVC}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `forest`, which has a somewhat simpler syntax and distributes the nodes efficiently without overlapping them. The `forked edges` option uses the `edges` library.

There are two somewhat complicated parts: First, to get the nodes aligned by level, use `tier/.pgfmath=level()`, which is a trick hidden on page 74 of the manual (version 2.1.5).

Second, drawing the edges to the node centers (`parent anchor=center`) for the first few levels allows a negative `l sep` so that the layers can overlap in the `x` dimension, but then the edges are drawn on top of the text. To fix that I redefined the built-in `draw tree edge/.code`, placing all edges on a background layer.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main}

\makeatletter
\forestset{draw tree edge/.code={\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}\forest@draw@edge\end{pgfonlayer}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=east, draw, forked edges,
    l sep=1pt, anchor=base, s sep=1pt, 
    tier/.pgfmath=level(),
    if level=1{red, edge=red}{if level=2{blue, edge=blue}{if level=3{teal, edge=teal}{if level=4{violet, edge=violet}{if level=5{gray, edge=gray}{}}}}},
    fill=white, font=\small
    }
[Human Variability, l sep=-1cm, parent anchor=center
    [Cognitive, l sep=-5mm, parent anchor=center
        [individual, l sep=-5mm, parent anchor=center
            [intra-personal
                [Situation Awareness]
                [Attention]
                [Motivation]
            ]
            [inter-personal
                [Cognitive Load
                    [Comprehension]
                    [Mental Capacity]
                ]
                [Experience]
                [Satisfaction]
                [Trust]
                [Curiosity]
                [Frustration]
                [Acceptability]
                [Usability]
                [Task Engagement]
            ]
        ]
        [Temporal, l sep=-5mm, parent anchor=center
            [Volatile
                [Curiosity]
                [Situation Awareness]
                [Attention]
                [Trust]
                [Frustration]
                [Task Engagement]
                [Motivation]
            ]
            [Consistent
                [Cognitive Load
                    [Comprehension]
                    [Mental Capacity]
                ]
                [Experience]
                [Satisfaction]
                [Acceptability]
                [Usability]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [Physical, l sep=-5mm, parent anchor=center
        [individual, l sep=-5mm, parent anchor=center
            [intra-personal
                [Motor Variability
                    [Motion Trajectory]
                    [Posture]
                    [Torque and Force]
                ]
                [Muscular Fatigue]
                [Heart Rate Variability (HRV)]
            ]
            [inter-personal
                [laterality (dominant hand)]
            ]
        ]
        [Temporal, l sep=-5mm, parent anchor=center
            [Volatile
                [Motor Variability
                    [Motion Trajectory]
                    [Posture]
                    [Torque and Force]
                ]
                [Heart Rate Variability (HRV)]
            ]
            [Consistent
                [laterality (dominant hand)]
                [Anthropometric Variability
                    [Body Dimensions]
                    [Gender]
                    [Age]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\caption{Human Variability Classification}
\label{fig:HVC}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```